# Не работает условие в PHP

Tags: php

```
 foreach($lists as $list){
            foreach($list as $row){

echo ceil($row[$cenav]) // Выводит целое число к примеру 560

if(ceil($row[$cenav]) > 1000){ 
    echo "ТЕСТ"; // А тут пусто...
}

  {
{
```

Почему не работает условие ?

Comment: 560 не больше 1000

Comment: Даже если вместо 560 будет 1000000 все равно не выводит

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `;` после `echo ceil($row[$cenav])`